# Visual Studio Code does not show variable color or problems anymore

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Recently while using Visual Studio code I noticed that the variable colors don't turn blue like they used to, and it does not show me problems in the code anymore. I particularly depend on this feature, so it "not showing problem" thing is a big issue for me. Would anyone know how can I get them back?

Also, this problem is in all of my Visual Studio Code tabs, so its not just a specific code doing it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It is probably because your color theme is changed.
To change it back go to "File", then "Preferences" and click on color themes. Select the "Dark+" theme

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to install a vs code plug-in called pylance and make sure that it is not disabled in your workspace.

Comment: Hey, I do already have Pylance installed and it is enabled too.

Comment: @poro123 Maybe you need to switch the language mode setting at the bottom right corner of VS Code to `Python`

Comment: It is already on python, apparently a classmate of mine has the same problem as I do.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread because my variables turned white instead of the blue color I expected. I was in Dark mode, but switched to Dark+ per another comment's recommendation. This doesn't seem to matter for me and I eventually switched back.

What mattered for me was that Pylint was enabled after Pylance.

To do this, I:

1. Disabled Pylint
2. Clicked "Reload Required"
3. Enabled Pylint

I disabled all my Python extensions in VS Code (Python, isort, etc.) shortly before this and re-enabled them, but I don't think this is necessary. Consider it a troubleshooting technique if the above does not resolve your issue.

Playing with my color theme after this also meant that I had to execute the steps again.

It seems that Pylance may be the source of this formatting, as other answers describe, since after step one and two, the blue color returns for me.

---

I ran into this again when I opened a different project and resorted to disabling and enabling all extensions again. I may have missed / ignored an error about a local server crash; here is a possibly related thread:
[I have a problem with python in vsCode: TypeError: .... is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77371542/i-have-a-problem-with-python-in-vscode-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

uninstall Visual Studio Code
and delete user\AppData\Roaming\Code (windows)
and the install it again,
may be it's due to a buggy extension or some setting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the picture and open your settings.

[image]

Check this option so that intellisence and error wavy lines will be back.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but sadly this didn't seem to fix my problem either.

Comment: @poro123 Can Python files work normally?

Comment: I think so, when I do the code it works normally, just doesn't show me the wavy error lines nor does it show the variables in color.

Comment: Backup the .vscode floder in the current workspace. And reselect the workspace to see if there is a prompt. Otherwise, I think you have to reinstall vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that running updates on some extensions reloaded VSCode and I got my syntax highlighting back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to install the language that you code in that. If you are coding a python code, make sure you installed the python in the extension of the Vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a silly mistake as me, I saved my file into a ".foldername" folder and it deactivated all the pylance functions.

In that case, only change the folder name and make sure there is no '.' at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what worked for me was reloading the test explorer UI extension if anyone else has it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and achieved to fix it by uninstalling then installing 1. python and 2. all python-related VScode extensions (I played with them yesterday and I guess I made something wrong)

My intuition is that you don't need to install/reinstall everything, but it worked for me.

Make a copy of your `settings.json` before in case of, I don't know if VSCode deletes configs related to an extension when you uninstall one.