# I have a problem with python in vsCode: TypeError: .... is not a function

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, the latest Pylance extension (v2023.10.50) failed with this error:

> TypeError: _0x2f33cc[(_0x1efd68(...) + _0x1efd68(...))] is not a
> function

(When I highlight on any line of code).

I tried to delete some suspected libs but nothing happened.

Comment: It would help if you shared the actual line of code you're highlighting, as well as any relevant code around it. Likely you have some expression followed by `()` (open and close parentheses) and whatever that expression evaluates into is not a function. But without actual code and some context, it's hard to say.

Comment: `_0x2f33cc` is a valid variable name but it looks like you execute obfuscated Python code

Comment: It's confirmed bug and they fixed it in Pre-Release version v2023.10.53.
https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5009

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The same error occurred when using Pylance v2023.10.50, and downgraded to v2023.10.40 and the problem was resolved.

Comment: This solved it for me, so thank you and have an upvote!

Comment: Probably we need also to add "extensions.autoUpdate": false to settings.json otherwise restarting vscode will automatically upgrade to the release which does not work.

Comment: Thanks, definetly need disable autoupdate

Answer (score 4):

Same error occured on Pylance v2023.10.50 when using venv, you can also use the pre-release version v2023.10.53 to fix the issue. To install it simply use the dropdown menu next to the install button in vscode extensions and select install pre-release version.